# Form.GotFocus disables close button

Tags: c#, windows, forms, winforms

I have a C# Windows Forms application which has a main form that opens two other forms in it's constructor. I'll call them side-panels.

The main form has the GotFocus event handled, which calls Form.BringToFront() for both the side-panel forms.

When this functionality is enabled(i.e. GotFocus is handled), the close button for the main form stops working.

How can I check if the close button was pressed in the event handler?

```
    public Canvas()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.GotFocus += new EventHandler(WindowGotFocus);

        tool.Show();
        pp.Show();
    }

    public void WindowGotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tool.BringToFront();
        pp.BringToFront();
    }
```

When I press the close button the main form, it gets focus, the WindowGotFocus method is called, and application does not close. If I comment 'this.GotFocus += new EventHandler(WindowGotFocus);' in the constructor, it works.

I need this functionality so that the side-panels are shown again if the use switches back to the application from another application.

Comment: You need to share your code, as whatever's happening is likely caused by the code somewhere. Can you explain what you mean by "stops working?" Do you mean that you have code that's not being called, or that you can't click it, or that the form doesn't close when you click it?

Comment: I've updated the question with code, and details of requirement and behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, of course it doesn't work. You caused the form to lose focus, which means that the click never happened as far as the window is concerned.

The proper way to handle this is by simply making the tool windows children of the main window:

```
var parent = new Form();
var child = new Form();

parent.AddOwnedForm(child);

parent.Show();
child.Show();
```

This will automatically handle the behaviour you expect - after all, you expect that behaviour because other applications *do the exact same thing* :) Apart from making sure the child windows show when the main window does, it also closes all child windows when the parent window is closed, among other things.